# Passenger load error - cannot load such file -- phusion_passenger (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

we have two applications on a virtual server running with Apache (2.4.6) + Passenger + Rails 4.0.0.

we had an issue with our server, caused by a ruby process consuming the 100% of CPU. After restarting the server, the ruby process is no longer running but also passenger is not starting.

Running passenger-status we get the error:

```
/home/adm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- phusion_passenger (LoadError)
from /home/adm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/sbin/passenger-status:27:in `<main>'
```

I'm not so expert with passenger so i have no idea on what is going on.

Any suggestion? Even to understand what the real problem is.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

running `bundle show passenger`

output `Could not find gem passenger`

PAssenger is loaded by apache in the virtual hosts of the applications:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.site1.it 
    ServerAlias site1.it       
    DocumentRoot /var/www/proj/current/public


    LoadModule passenger_module /home/adm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dentist/gems/passenger-4.0.37/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
    <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
        PassengerRoot /home/adm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dentist/gems/passenger-4.0.37
        PassengerDefaultRuby /home/adm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@dentist/wrappers/ruby
    </IfModule>

        RailsEnv production
        PassengerLogLevel 3
        PassengerMinInstances 1
        <Directory /var/www/proj/current/public>

                # This relaxes Apache security settings.
                AllowOverride all
                # MultiViews must be turned off.
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.site2.it 
    ServerAlias site2.it       
    DocumentRoot /var/www/proj/current/public

    RequestHeader Set X-Sendfile-Type X-Sendfile
    XSendFile On

    LoadModule passenger_module /home/adm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@police/gems/passenger-4.0.37/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
    <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
          PassengerRoot /home/adm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@police/gems/passenger-4.0.37
          PassengerDefaultRuby /home/adm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@police/wrappers/ruby
        </IfModule>

        RailsEnv production
        PassengerLogLevel 3
        PassengerMinInstances 1
        <Directory /var/www/proj/current/public>

                # This relaxes Apache security settings.
                AllowOverride all
                # MultiViews must be turned off.
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: two questions, please show script that runs the passnger, and result of command run: `bundle show passenger` of the project's root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i found in my apache error.log

```
An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time. Please read <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems">this article</a> for more information about this problem.<br>
```

so i added PassengerStartTimeout 300 to my apache configuration file and it started working again even if very slowly. The problem with the ruby process persists but i will ask another question.